# Error when loading html with flash page using https in Internet Explorer

Tags: apache-flex, flash, internet-explorer, iis-7, https

I have a html page which loads a flash(flex) swf file. Using https it loads successfully with Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not with Internet Explorer.

Another page, a simple aspx page, does load in Internet Explorer using https (and no flash in it).

Haven't found anything so far on the internet to solve this. Anyone?

UPDATE: When I right click on the white screen, 'About Adobe Flash Player 10...' appears... so Flash is loaded. Also, in Charles (http sniffer tool) I can see that the swf is loaded over the network...

So, apparently, Flash Player is running inside my html page, the swf is loaded over the internet but the swf is not displayed in internet explorer browser. How can I debug this further to see what the problem is?

Meanwhile, in the left down corner, IE keeps on saying: 'Waiting for https://...

In all other browsers it works like a charm.

You can see that IE shows a Certificate Error, but that's also the case in other browsers. I already clicked on Certificate Error to install the Certificate, but with no success.

Comment: not strange at all that IE and apsx works :)). Anyway... check out if you don;t have somehow any JavaScript errors inside you html. Is that HTML the default one that is created by flex builder when you release the project ?

Comment: Hi, it is the main one, but not a recently created one (we have put it in svn couple of years ago and keep working with that file), so I'll try once with a newly created one to see if it works.

No errors in javascript + it does load in all other browsers so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is choking on the headers. Details on how to fix this issue here:
http://www.gmrweb.net/2005/08/18/flash-remoting-https-internet-explorer/